# How can I add a local (non-internet) time server?

Tags: networking, router, ntp

I'm trying to set up a doorphone system (SIP-based doorbell).

In most cases, this would use a SIP server and be connected to the internet however at this time I need to install one at a location that cannot have an internet connection and I am making it all local.

**The issue that I'm facing is that the doorphone does not hold the time after a power cycle.**
I need the time in order to enforce door access scheduling.

The solution I'm thinking of is to have a local ntp time server (the router or something cheap to add in)

This is the router I used there: TL-WR940N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TL-WR940N cannot function as an NTP master, because its firmware
does not expose such a function.

You should get a router with a more evolved firmware, such as
[DD-WRT](https://dd-wrt.com/), which is Linux-based and supports the WR940N.
You may flash the WR940N with DD-WRT, or get a router with DD-WRT
already installed.

As DD-WRT is basically Linux, you may install ntpd.
If the DD-WRT repository doesn't contain ntpd, try installing
[Entware](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Installing_Entware).
Entware is a software repository for embedded devices like routers and
has more than 1800 packages available.